# Error PHP- Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysqli

Obtengo el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   llam_componentes() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaweb\researchLabotatory\inventario\versala.php:95
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaweb\researchLabotatory\inventario\versala.php on
>   line 95

este es mi código:

```
<?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['ACTUAL_PAG']."config.php");

    if(isset($_GET['sala'])){
        $sala = $_GET['sala'];
    }
    $title = $sala;
    $actualpagina = str_replace(' ', '', $sala);
?>
<?php include($ruta_php."head.php"); ?>

<!--  CABECERA -->
<?php include($ruta_php."navegacion.php"); ?>

<!-- IMAGEN ENTRANTE -->
<?php include($ruta_php."cabecera.php");?>
<!-- MAIN -->
<?php
    //SI POR ALGÚN CASUAL NO SE RECIBE LA VARIABLE, NO MUESTRA NADA
    //DE ESA FORMA NO MOSTRARÁ NINGUN ERROR, NO EJECUTARÁ NADA
    //TAMBIEN EVITA QUE LA GENTE SE META EN LA PÁGINA DIRECTAMENTE CON EL LINK (por ejemplo: xxx/versala.php ) YA QUE ASÍ
    //NO ENVIA NINGUNA VARIABLE (ejemplo correcto: xxx/versala.php?sala="XXXX")
    if(isset($_GET['sala'])){
        $sala = $_GET['sala'];
?>
<table class="tablepuestos">
<!--    NOMBRE DE LAS COLUMNAS  -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <!--    PARA AÑADIR MÁS     -->
            <?php if($_SESSION['tipo']=="administrador"){echo '<a href="'.$ruta_html.'adminpanel.php#crearElemento" class="addmore" title="Añadir nuevos elementos">+</a>';}?>
            Component Ref
        </th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>SubCategory</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Doc</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!--    BODY PARA MOSTRAR EL CONTENIDO  -->
<tbody>
<?php
    if(!$inv_conexion){
        men_error(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else{
        //  TODOS LOS SELECT DE LAS TABLAS NECESARIAS
        $sql_elemento="SELECT * FROM elemento";
        $sql_puesto="SELECT * FROM puesto";
        $sql_sala="SELECT * FROM sala WHERE nombre='".$sala."'";
        $sql_estado="SELECT * FROM estado";

        //DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES
        $idsala="";
        $arraycomponentes=array();

        //SELECCIONAMOS LA SALA
        $sala_result=mysqli_query($inv_conexion,$sql_sala);

        if(!$sala_result){
            men_error("Imposible conectar con la tabla SALA de la base de datos");
        }
        else{
            $sala_count=mysqli_num_rows($sala_result);
            //SI NO EXISTE LA SALA SIMPLEMENTE MUESTRA QUE NO EXISTE
            if($sala_count>0){
                while($sala_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($sala_result)){
                    $idsala=$sala_fila["id_sala"];
                }
                //AQUI HAGO UNA CONSULTA A LA TABLA elemento
                //EL TRUCO AQUÍ PARA QUE NO APAREZCAN DATOS REPETIDOS ES EL
                //DISTINCT. QUE SI EL ID_ESTADO Y ID_COMPONENTES SON DISTINTOS
                //ENTONCES LO MUESTRA
                $sql_elemento="SELECT DISTINCT id_estado, id_componentes FROM elemento WHERE id_sala='".$idsala."'";
                $elem_result=mysqli_query($inv_conexion,$sql_elemento);
                if(!$elem_result){
                    men_error("Imposible conectar con la tabla ELEMENTO de la base de datos");
                }
                else{
                    $elem_count=mysqli_num_rows($elem_result);
                    if($elem_count>0){
                        while($elem_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($elem_result)){
                            //LLAMADA A LA TABLA COMPONENTES. DEVUELVE UN ARRAY CON TODA LA INFORMACIÓN
                            //  0 COMPONENT_REF
                            //  1 SUBCATEGORIA
                            //  2 CATEGORIA
                            //  3 NOMBRE
                            //  4 LINK

                            //  LINEA 95 JUSTO DEBAJO
                            $id_componentes=$elem_fila['id_componentes'];
                            $id_estado=$elem_fila['id_estado'];
                            $arraycomponentes=llam_componentes($id_componentes);
                            //LLAMADA AL NOMBRE DEL ESTADO
                            $estado=llam_estado($id_estado);

                            //CUENTA CUANTAS FILAS TIENEN EL MISMO ID COMPONENTE Y EL MISMO ESTADO
                            $cantidad_result=mysqli_query($inv_conexion,"SELECT * FROM elemento WHERE id_componentes='".$id_componentes."' AND id_estado='".$id_estado."'");
                            $cantidad=mysqli_num_rows($cantidad_result);

                            //EL DOC - TEORIA:
                            //El doc son ficheros en los que se va almacenando la información de cada componente
                            //por ejemplo: el metodo de uso, el manual, la descripción, etc.
                            //simplemente es para tener un poco más de información sobre un componente en concreto
                            $documento=$ruta_php."doc/".$arraycomponentes[0].".php";
                            if(file_exists($documento)){
                                $fichero="<a href='".$ruta_html."doc/".$arraycomponentes[0]."'>DOC</a>";
                            }
                            else{
                                $fichero="<a href='' class='noexist'>DOC</a>";
                            }
                            //MOSTRAR EN PANTALLA
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$arraycomponentes[0]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$arraycomponentes[3]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$arraycomponentes[2]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$arraycomponentes[1]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$cantidad."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$estado."</td>";
                            echo "<td><a href='".$arraycomponentes[4]."'>Link</a></td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fichero."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $nocontenido="No existe ningun elemento que este en ".$sala;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                $nocontenido="No hay ninguna ".$sala;
            }
        }
    }

    //FUNCION DE LLAMADA A LA TABLA COMPONTNETES
    function llam_componentes($id){
        $sql_componentes="SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE id_componentes='".$id."'";
        $compo_result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['inv_conexion'],$sql_componentes);
        $arraycompo = array();
        if(!$compo_result){
            men_error("Imposible conectar con la tabla COMPONENTES de la base de datos");
        }
        else{
            $compo_count=mysqli_num_rows($compo_result);
            if($compo_count>0){
                while($compo_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($compo_result)){
                    //ESTABLECER EN EL ARRAY LOS VALORES
                    $arraycompo[0]=$compo_fila["component_ref"];
                    $arraycompo[1]=llam_subcategoria(2,$compo_fila['id_subcategoria']);
                    $arraycompo[2]=llam_subcategoria(1,$compo_fila['id_subcategoria']);
                    $arraycompo[3]=$compo_fila['nombre'];
                    $arraycompo[4]=$compo_fila['link'];
                    //RETORNAR EL ARRAY
                    return $arraycompo;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //FUNCION DE LLAMADA A LA TABLA SUBCATEGORIA
    function llam_subcategoria($tipo,$id){
        $sql_subcategoria="SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE id_subcategoria='".$id."'";
        $subcat_result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['inv_conexion'],$sql_subcategoria);
        if(!$subcat_result){
            men_error("Imposible conectar con la tabla SUBCATEGORIA de la base de datos");
        }
        else{
            $subcat_count=mysqli_num_rows($subcat_result);
            if($subcat_count>0){
                while($subcat_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($subcat_result)){
                    //ESTO ES PARA DEVOLVER EL NOMBRE DE CATEGORIA O SUBCATEGORIA
                    //DEPENDIENDO DEL TIPO QUE LLAMES
                    switch($tipo){
                        case 1:
                            return $subcat_fila['nombre'];
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            return llam_categoria($subcat_fila['id_categoria']);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //FUNCION DE LLAMADA A LA TABLA CATEGORIA
    //NO TIENE MUCHO MISTERIO...
    function llam_categoria($id){
        $sql_categoria="SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE id_categoria='".$id."'";
        $cat_result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['inv_conexion'],$sql_categoria);
        if(!$cat_result){
            men_error("Imposible conectar con la tabla CATEGORIA de la base de datos");
        }
        else{
            $cat_count=mysqli_num_rows($cat_result);
            if($cat_count>0){
                while($cat_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($cat_result)){
                    return $cat_fila["nombre"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //FUNCION DE LLAMADA A LA TABLA ESTADO
    //NO TIENE MUCHO MISTERIO...
    function llam_estado($id){
        //$sql_estado="SELECT * FROM estado WHERE id_estado='".$id."'";
        $estad_result=mysqli_query($FLOBALS["inv_conexion"],$sql_estado);
        if(!$estad_result){
            men_error("Imposible conectar con la tabla estado de la base de datos");
        }
        else{
            $estad_count=mysqli_num_rows($estad_result);
            if($estad_count>0){
                while($estad_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($estad_result)){
                    return $estad_fila["estado"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- SI NO HAY CONTENIDO SE MUESTRA UN MENSAJE-->
<p class="sincontenido"><?php echo $nocontenido ?></p>
<?php 
//CIERRE DE IF, SI NO RECIBE LA VARIABLE DEL POST
    }
    else{
        men_error("Ha ocurrido un error inesperado");
    }
?>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<?php include($ruta_php."footer.php"); ?>
```

Bueno, que contar... Basicamente me da ese error y no entiendo ni porque ya que estoy utilizando mysqli_ incluso lo he pasado por un php validator para que me encuentre algún fallo y nada

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Particularmente encuentro extraña la forma en que tienes montado tu código: hay al menos tres consultas a la base de datos anidadas, y dentro de un `while`. ¿Por qué haces eso?  Sugiero que pruebes tu código sin esas consultas... llamando de una función a otra con simples `echo` .... si funciona así entonces es un problema de esa anidación de consultas. Fíjate, ni siquiera recomendaría una sola consulta dentro de un `while`, mucho menos dos o tres... Si hay 1000 elementos haces 3000 consultas a la BD. Eso no es bueno.

Comment: O sea... dentro de un `while` que trae resultados de la base de datos: llamas a dos funciones que cada una de ellas consulta también a la base de datos, y luego de llamar a esas dos funciones, lanzas desde dentro del `while` oooootra consulta más a la base de datos. ¡  ! ¿Acaso tus tablas no están relacionadas? ¿Por qué no traes todos los datos usando una sola consulta?

Comment: Es simple estas llamando a una funcion antes de crearla :v

Comment: @Bryro el que la función esté más abajo de donde se la llama no importa, el código no falla por eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano anido varias consultas para retornar el nombre de los campos y no las id. Ya que son relaciones entre tablas y tambien consulto varios campos (como puede ser en la tabla componentes). Y luego consulto la información, se que es una manera rudimentaria de hacerlo. Pero no se me ocurre otra forma/conozco. Tengo otro fichero que hace lo mismo simplemente que en vez de retornar un array retorna un valor con un switch

Comment: Basicamente lo que estoy intentando hacer con esta tabla es tener una tabla general que llama a otras bases de datos que tienen más información. Y quiero mostrar esa información (sala/puesto:lugar. Estado:estado del elemento, componentes:el tipo de compmonente que es y elemento que es el general que llama a todos esos datos)

Comment: Como ha dicho @Bryro en los comentarios he puesto las funciones arriba y funciona perfectamente.... Aunque yo diría que no importa absolutamente nada que este arriba o abajo pero OKAAAY :D Actualización 28/11
Al final he hecho un <code>INNER JOIN</code> para llamar a las tablas y he modificado todo el codigo, funciona perfectamente